# How do I force dnsmasq to use a specific DNS server without affecting the host systems DNS settings?

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

How do I set `dnsmasq` to use one specific DNS server without changing which DNS server the host system uses for its own DNS requests?

I should clarify I am not using dnsmasq as a DHCP server but only to forward the DNS requests on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send specific dns addresses to the clients set

```
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`.

In this example `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are google public dns.

Comment: can it be redirected server with port other than 53